# css frame layout isn't working properly in IE 6 and above

Tags: css, internet-explorer, scroll, positioning, frames

I am trying to make a CSS page layout using DIVs to emulate frames.

I want a fixed top pane that has a fixed height and the width stretches and shrinks as the page is resized. (fixed meaning if the user scrolls down the page, the top pane is always visible)

Below that I want two columns. The left column has a fixed width and the right column stretches in width as you resize the window. Both columns should have vertical scrollbars when necessary.

My code seems to work fine in Chrome, but in IE, the scrollbars don't show up in the left or the right columns.

Is there something I can do to fix this? Maybe some javascript to tell IE to draw the scrollbars properly?

style:

```
body{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%; 
    max-height: 100%; 
}

#framecontentTop{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px; 
    left: 0px; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 108px; /*Height of frame div*/
    overflow: hidden; /*Disable scrollbars. Set to "scroll" to enable*/
    background-color: navy;
    color: white;
}

#framecontent{
    position: absolute;
    top: 108px;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;    
    width: 200px; /*Width of frame div*/
    float:right;
    overflow: auto; /*Disable scrollbars. Set to "scroll" to enable*/
    background: navy;
    color: white;
    /*padding: 108px 0 0 200px; */ /*Set value to (0 0 0 WidthOfFrameDiv)*/
}


#maincontent{
    position: absolute;
    top: 108px; 
    left: 200px; /*Set left value to WidthOfFrameDiv*/
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    float:right;
    overflow: auto; 
    background: #fff;
}


* html body { /*IE6 hack*/

}


* html #maincontent{ /*IE6 hack*/
    height: 100%; 
    width: 100%; 
}
```

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/*** Temporary text filler function. Remove when deploying template. ***/
var gibberish=["This is just some filler text", "Welcome to Dynamic Drive CSS Library", "Demo content nothing to read here"]
function filltext(words){
for (var i=0; i<words; i++)
document.write(gibberish[Math.floor(Math.random()*3)]+" ")
}
</script>
```

html body:

```
<div id="framecontentTop">
<h1>CSS Top Frame Layout</h1>
<h3>Sample text here</h3>
</div>


<div id="framecontent">
<h1>CSS Left Frame Layout</h1>
<p><script type="text/javascript">filltext(25)</script></p>
</div>


<div id="maincontent">
<h1>Dynamic Drive CSS Library</h1>
<p><script type="text/javascript">filltext(255)</script></p>
<p style="text-align: center">Credits: <a href="http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/">Dynamic Drive CSS Library</a></p>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please reformat the code in your question, the box below the input box (textarea), you can preview your post before you submit it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set heights on the #maincontent and #framecontent divs or they will never scroll, they will just stretch to fit their contents.  The % height may cause trouble for IE, and it can cause unexpected results (in my humble experience).  Have you tried removing the IE only CSS?

Also, to correct a comment in your CSS, overflow: auto doesn't disable scrollbars.  It hides them when they aren't needed and shows them when they are.